# Click of li display content in iframe on same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a one html page and top of the page I am display the some menu `.under` menu having some li. Now I want to click on any li and displaying the content of each li below the iframe:

```
<div class='main_container'>
  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          Tea <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li role="presentation"><a href="test.html">Tea1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="test2.html">Tea2</a></li>
          
        </ul>
      </li>
      
       <div id="nav">
       <iframe id='link'></iframe>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Comment: can any one tell me how i can  display each li href in same iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use   `target="iframe"`

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/47tub983/